# Regex 11 digit string capturing

Tags: c#, regex

```
String pattern = @"^(\d{11})$";
String input = "You number is:11126564312 and 12234322121 \n\n23211212345";
Match match = Regex.Match(input,pattern);
```

From the above code I am planning to capture the 11 digit strings present in above text but match.Success is always returning false. Any ideas.

Comment: You *do* know what `^` and `$` mean, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is because you have used `^` and `$`**.

**Explaination:** The meaning of your regular expression is "*match any string that contains exactly 11 digits from start to end*". The string `You number is:11126564312 and 12234322121 \n\n23211212345` is not a string like that. `01234567890` is like that string.

**What you need:** You need regular expression for *match any string that contains exactly 11 digits*. *start to end* is omitted. `^` and `$` is used for this. So you need this regex.

```
String pattern = @"(\d{11})";
```

As the sub-pattern to capture contains the whole regex you dont need `()` at all. Just the regex ill do.

```
String pattern = @"\d{11}";
```

Comment: No, you don't need the `Singleline` option.  All it does is change the meaning of the dot (`.`) so it matches any character *including* linefeeds, and there are no dots in this regex.  This is a variation on another rogue meme I've been seeing a lot: "The input is multiline, therefore you must use `Multiline` mode."  In reality, you only need `Multiline` if you want `^` and `$` to match at line boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

```
String pattern = @"^(\d{11})$";
String input = "11126564312" 
Match match = Regex.Match(input,pattern);
```

will pass.

Your Regex specify it has to be 11 numbers ONLY

`^` = starts with
`$` = ends with

if you want to check if it **contains** 11 numbers change the regex to

```
String pattern = @"\d{11}";
```

Comment: gdoron: The OP asked for the correct regex for the input. Telling him to change his input is not helpful. You added the correct regex after my downvote. I would remove my downvote now but I cannot until you edit your post.

Answer (score 3):

Your Regex matches a string that has exactly 11 digits, but no text before, between or after. That is why you don't get any matches here.

To match 11 digits anywhere in the string, simply use:

```
string pattern = @"\d{11}";
```